# How does one release a *nix project?

Tags: unix, haskell, installation

So, I've written a neat little program that can analyse Japanese text and give the user various statistics regarding [Kanji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji) usage therein and I'd like to release this program to the world. The problem is, I have no idea how to create a "release".

I realize that *nix systems often put executables (or symlinks) in places like /usr/bin, and that build scripts often put them there automatically, but it turns out I went and wrote this thing in Haskell.

> Then just use cabal!

...I hear you say. Well I would, except that my program has a good amount of data files that it reads out of, and of course the program needs to know where those files are. By using cabal, would the executable not be thrown to some weird project filepath a la:

> /usr/share/haskell/cabal/morecabal-1.0.4/myproject-1.3.4.1.a/thisisridiculous/

At current I run the executable out of its source directory, and it's looking for the data files in "./data".
Is there a typical format for installation paths so I could tell my program ahead of time in the source where to look for the data?

My eventual goal is to make this an Arch Linux package. Can anyone help me get started?

For the curious, the [git repo is here](https://github.com/fosskers/nanq). Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at how an existing Haskell project, such as [Gitit](http://gitit.net/) is packaged [for Arch linux](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=21349). In particular, the PKGBUILD.

You can also download [The gitit tarball](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gitit/0.7.3.8/gitit-0.7.3.8.tar.gz) and have a look at how to use the `data-files:` directive in the `gitit.cabal` file.

I don't read Haskell, but from what I understand of the source, the file `Paths_gigit.hs` (which can be found [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gitit/0.7.3.4/doc/html/src/Paths_gitit.html). ) is generated by cabal so that you only have to worry about relative paths. Then it's just a matter of importing it and using the `getDataFileName` function.

#### Packaging for Arch:

- The [wiki guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_Packages)
- The PKGBUILD [file description](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD)
- The [makepkg guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg#Usage)

#### Packaging for cabal:

- Haskell Packaging [wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Packaging)
- The [Cabal User's Guide](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/)

#### Packaging for both:

- Haskell Package [guidelines](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haskell_package_guidelines) on the Archlinux wiki

Comment: I shall climb the nearest mountain, meditate at the peak and not descend until I understand the PKGBUILD use of the data-files parameter. Thank you.

Comment: Also, `data-files` is in the `gitit.cabal` file, rather than the PKGBUILD.

Comment: You might also take a look at the haskell-pandoc PKGBUILD.  pandoc (by the same author) might be a little simpler. If you are looking ahead to wider usability, note that the pandoc source includes a script for making a regular os x installer https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/make_osx_package.sh and even one for windows; the binaries end up here http://code.google.com/p/pandoc/downloads/list ; they put everything in sensible places with the right paths and don't involve the user getting a copy of ghc and so on.

Comment: Cheers applicative. Also just noticed the [Haskell package Guidlenies](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haskell_package_guidelines#Guidelines_for_Libraries) on the Archlinux wiki. They give Pandoc as an example too.

Comment: There should have been an "and" after PKGBUILD there... twas a typo, not my lack of understanding ;)

Answer (score 12):

The portable way of referencing data files in a Cabal project is to name them in the `data-files` property in your `.cabal` file.

Cabal will generate a module called `Paths_packagename` which defines a function

```
getDataFileName :: FilePath -> IO FilePath
```

which your code can use to determine where the data files got installed.

See: [Accessing data files from package code](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#accessing-data-files-from-package-code)

Comment: So cabal is the way to go afterall.

Comment: @fosskers: You may also want to look into the various tools available on Hackage for making distribution-specific packages from a Cabal package, like [cabal2arch](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal2arch).